# Best way to pass a mathematical operator through method parameters

Tags: c++, templates, math, methods, parameters

As the question suggests I have a method as follows:

```
template<typename LN, typename RN, typename LV, typename RV>
VariableValue dataArithmetic(LN leftNode, RN rightNode, LV leftV, RV rightV) {

    if (leftNode.type() == typeid(ChartData*) && rightNode.type() == typeid(ChartData*)) {
        ChartData* temp1 = boost::get<ChartData*>(leftNode);
        ChartData* temp2 = boost::get<ChartData*>(rightNode);
        temp1->data *= temp2->data; // <----------------
        return temp1;
    }
    else if (leftNode.type() == typeid(ChartData*) || rightNode.type() == typeid(ChartData*)) {
        if (leftNode.type() == typeid(ChartData*)) {
            ChartData* temp = boost::get<ChartData*>(leftNode);
            float value = boost::lexical_cast<float>(rightV);
            temp->data *= value; // <----------------
            return (VariableValue)temp;
        }
        else if (rightNode.type() == typeid(ChartData*)) {
            ChartData* temp = boost::get<ChartData*>(rightNode);
            float value = boost::lexical_cast<float>(leftV);
            temp->data *= value; // <----------------
            return (VariableValue)temp;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Currently this method is coded to apply multiplication, as depicted by `// <----------------`
However I need this method to support all basic arithmetic values + - * /

Considering that this function is called by:

```
VariableValue dataArith = dataArithmetic(leftNode, rightNode, leftV, rightV);
```

I would like the method to take a parameter that specifies which mathematical operator should be applied such as:

```
VariableValue dataArith = dataArithmetic(leftNode, rightNode, leftV, rightV, **MULTIPLICATION**);
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template the function on the operation:

```
template<typename LN, typename RN, typename LV, typename RV, typename OP>
VariableValue dataArithmetic(LN leftNode, RN rightNode, LV leftV, RV rightV, OP op) {
```

And then pass an appropriate operation:

```
dataArithmetic(..., std::multiplies<>{})
dataArithmetic(..., std::plus<>{})
dataArithmetic(..., std::minus<>{})
dataArithmetic(..., std::divides<>{})
```

Before C++14, those function objects in the standard library need template parameters (`std::multiplies<double>{}`). C++14 or after, they do not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how would I use `OP` in replacement of `temp1->data *= temp2->data;`?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `std::binary_function` or just `std::function`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeff Garrett for the pointer

Solution:

```
template<typename LN, typename RN, typename LV, typename RV, typename OP>
VariableValue dataArithmetic(LN leftNode, RN rightNode, LV leftV, RV rightV, OP op) {

    if (leftNode.type() == typeid(ChartData*) && rightNode.type() == typeid(ChartData*)) {
        ChartData* temp1 = boost::get<ChartData*>(leftNode);
        ChartData* temp2 = boost::get<ChartData*>(rightNode);
        //;
        ChartData* temp = new ChartData(op(temp1->data, temp2->data));
        return temp1;
    }
    else if (leftNode.type() == typeid(ChartData*) || rightNode.type() == typeid(ChartData*)) {
        if (leftNode.type() == typeid(ChartData*)) {
            ChartData* temp1 = boost::get<ChartData*>(leftNode);
            float value = boost::lexical_cast<float>(rightV);
            ChartData* temp = new ChartData(op(temp1->data, value));
            return (VariableValue)temp;
        }
        else if (rightNode.type() == typeid(ChartData*)) {
            ChartData* temp1 = boost::get<ChartData*>(rightNode);
            float value = boost::lexical_cast<float>(leftV);
            ChartData* temp = new ChartData(op(temp1->data, value));
            return (VariableValue)temp;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To call:

```
VariableValue dataArith = dataArithmetic(leftNode, rightNode, leftV, rightV, std::multiplies<>{});
```